# Get either end of the month or current date + a few days based on current date

Tags: date, sqlite, case-when

I have to write a query to either get all records due before end of current month or records due before 15(or X) days after current date whichever is larger in sqlite. Is this even possible?  I have tried the following case when statement

```
select case when date('now', 'start of month', '+1 month', '-1 day')
> date('now', '+15 day') then date('now', 'start of month', 
'+1 month', '-1 day') else date('now', '+15 day');
```

I get the following error

Error: near ";": syntax error

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why do you have that second select in there?

Comment: @Shawn thanks. I removed the second select and now I'm getting Error: near ";": syntax error

Comment: You're also missing the `END`s from those `CASE` expressions.

Comment: Hey thanks!!! Its working!!!! If you can post this as an answer i will accept it as answered.